# form input will not POST to MYSQL but will show on screen

Tags: php, mysql

The form sends the data to this page. The print_r outputs everything I want to put into the table onscreen to check it's there, but nothing goes to the table. I have only managed to populate the table manually in phpmyadmin. Iam sorry if it's a really easy fix - I have only been learning for two weeks!
There are no errors showing in the logs or on screen when I run the page. The print_r  does echo the array as it should be but nothing appears in the table

```
<?php


session_start();
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'users';

$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);
$companyName = ($_POST['companyName']);
$confirmPassword = ($_POST['confirmPassword']);

// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, 
$DATABASE_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and 
    display the error.
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());


    }



    print_r ($_POST);


    // Now we check if the data was submitted, isset() function will check 
    //if  the data exists.
    if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], 
    $_POST['companyName'])) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Please complete the registration form!');
    }

    // Make sure the submitted registration values are not empty.
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || 
    empty($_POST['companyName'])) {
    // One or more values are empty.
    die ('Please complete the registration form');
    }
    print_r ($_POST);

    // We need to check if the account with that username exists.
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM phplogin WHERE 
    username = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the 
    //password using the PHP password_hash function.
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

     // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the 
    // database.
     if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    // Username already exists
    echo 'Username exists, please choose another!';
    } else {
    // Username doesnt exists, insert new account
    /* $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO phplogin (username, password, 
      companyName ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');*/ 

    if (false !== true){
        /* We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the 
        password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['$username'], $password, 
        $_POST['$companyName']);
        $stmt->execute();*/
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO phplogin (username, password, companyName ) 
        VALUES ($username, $password, $companyName)';
        echo 'You have successfully registered, you can now login!';
        echo ("  ".$password." ".$username."  ".$companyName);
        echo '  well done';

    } else {
        /* Something is wrong with the sql statement, check to make sure accounts table exists with all 3 fields.*/
        echo 'Could not prepare the new statement!';
        print_r ($_POST);
        }
        }
        }



        $con->close();

        ?>
```

Comment: Check stmt for errors after you execute it.

Comment: Don't check the account exists, this is a race condition. Have a UNIQUE/Primary key on the username which prevents duplicates from being inserted.

Comment: OK - will change that bit with the primary key. I thought the last else statement checked the stmt?

Comment: I have commented the stmt out, commented everything else out, re-run the code and get the success echo, but still nothing in the table! Error reporting is on (ALL),  it echos the variables, it even checks to see if there  is already an account of the same name - so I know it's connecting to the right place, but both braincells are getting frustrated with this!

Comment: Hey Glafuski !! have worked it out!! I still had the $_POST variables in the INSERT stmnt, but had declared the $variable = ($_POST['variable']); at the top of the page. I changed to $variable in the stmt using your  advice on the IF($stmt === true) and we have lift-off! I will look into PDO as soon as I can, I really appreciate your help and have learned from your comments - so just wanted to say thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//$sql = 'INSERT INTO phplogin (username, password, companyName ) VALUES ($_POST[username], $password, $_POST[companyName])';
```

PHP thinks it should execute VALUES even though it is not any proper action. Use /* THIS IS COMMENT */ because it prevents stuff like this happening.

Also as a side note: Do not assign values in if statement. You can assign $stmt on its own line and just check

```
If($stmt === true) {}
```

Or

```
If($stmt !== true) {}
```

You get the point.

Also another side note is that you should prefer using PDO. It is alot of easier to handle and understand because of ts syntax and it makes OOP much much more easier. Mysqli is ok to use, but i personally do not recommend using it.